# Canonically quantizing the charged scalar field with massive gauge boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I have a specific confusion in canonically quantizing the theory of a complex scalar field $\Phi$ and a real vector field $V^\mu$, with a Lagrangian density:
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L} = -(D_\mu \Phi)^{\dagger}D^\mu\Phi - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}m^2 V_\mu V^\mu - \mathcal{H}(\Phi^\dagger\Phi) \ ,
\end{align*}
where $D_\mu \equiv \partial_\mu - i g V_\mu$ and $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{[\mu}V_{\nu]} \ .$

Here is my attempt with the point of confusion noted:
First step is to expand this Lagrangian and identify the conjugate fields. Expanding the Lagrangian gives us:
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L} = -(\partial_\mu \Phi)^{\dagger}\partial^\mu\Phi - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}m^2 V_\mu V^\mu - ig V_\mu (\Phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \Phi - \Phi (\partial^\mu \Phi)^\dagger) - g^2 V^2 |\Phi|^2 - \mathcal{H}(\Phi^\dagger\Phi)
\end{align*}

There is no mass term for the scalar field here, but we can pull it out of the arbitrary function if needs be, but the scalar field could very well be massless. Also, we can choose:

$$J^\mu = - ig (\Phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \Phi - \Phi \partial^\mu \Phi^\dagger)$$

In any case, we get the following conjugate fields:
\begin{align*}
    \Pi = \dot{\Phi}^\dagger - i g V^0 \Phi^\dagger\\
    \Pi^\dagger = \dot{\Phi} + i g V^0 \Phi\\
    P^i = F^{i0} = \dot{V}^i + \partial_i V^0
\end{align*}

Now, $P^0 = 0$, so $V^0$ is just an auxiliary field, we can use the equation of motion ($-\partial_i F^{i0} = J^0 - 2 g^2 V^0 |\Phi|^2 - m^2 V^0$) to eliminate it in terms of the canonical field variable. This will help us in switching from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian formalism. But, I get:

$$V^0 = \frac{\nabla \cdot P + J^0}{(2g^2|\Phi|^2 + m^2)}$$

I was wondering if I can do that, i.e. just divide by a function of a field?

I am following Weinberg's approach for quantization.